# Invoke Method of instance class through string

Tags: c#, methods, element, watin, invoke

this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19911/Dynamically-Invoke-A-Method-Given-Strings-with-Met
explains clearly how to invoke a method when you have a method name + type as string variable.

I'm making a c# project with WatiN. All the WatiN methods I use are of the same form:

**Examples:** *(*ById,.ByClass..; so should be connected, but then I could not set it bold :s )*

- `browser.**TextField**(Find.By **Id**("name")).**TypeText**("my name");`
- `browser.**Span**(Find.By **Class**("main_title")).**Click(**);`
- `browser.**Link**(Find.By **Id**("mid_link")).**Click(**);`

As you can see, this always consist of 3 methods which are variable. I created a class webElement consisted of the string properties: tag, type, search, action.

Where in example -> `tag = "TextField"; type = "Id", search = "name"; action = "TypeText"`.

To get the web-elements dynamically, I created a WebHandler class where I try to dynamically call the right methods.

So a main class has a list of all the webElement objects and can give the right one at a given time to the WebHandler class. The Webhandler class should now invoke each element dynamically. I use the same invoke method as in given url, so my code to call it is:

**class WebHandler:**

```
private IE browser = new IE("google.com");

public void method(WebElement webElement)
{
     //Get the findBy dynamically | this works
     WatiN.Core.Constraints.Constraint findBy =
                (WatiN.Core.Constraints.Constraint)InvokeMethod("WatiN.Core.Find, WatiN.Core", "By" + webElement.Type, webElement.Search); //where type = "Id" and search = "name"

     //Get the tag (like textfield, link, span) dynamically | this does not work
     Type aType = Type.GetType("WatiN.Core." + webElement.Tag, "WatiN.Core") //how can I set the element variable to this type? aType element -> Does not work
     aType element = (WatiN.Core.TextField)InvokeMethod("this.browser", webElement.Tag, findBy); //tag = TextField

    element.TypeText("a name"); //same problem as above | so should be invoked
}
```

QUESTIONS:

1. How do I invoke method (**TextField**) of instance class IE
   (**browser**) dynamically using his string version "TextField" as variable? Another way of phrasing it would be: How do I get current variable (**browser**) by using it's string version "browser"?
2. How do I set type of variable **element** dynamically? So when webElement.Tag  = Textfield then type should be WatiN.Core.TexField
   element = .. (see code)

OWN CONSIDERATIONS:

1. Main problem I found is that you can only invoke a method from a type, so not from an instance of that type. Is there a way to do this anyway?

Comment: There is no actual question here.

Comment: Very Interesting , what's your point..? most of all what's your actual Question..?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I mentioned the questions at bot now :)

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
Type aType = Type.GetType("WatiN.Core" + webElement.Tag)
```

does not have a dot after `Core`.  It seems as if `Core` is a namespace and should thus be separated from the Tag name.

Answer (score 0):

The gist of this is you get the Type you want, then use reflection to get the methods, then invoke the given method, passing the instance in.

So, something like this:

```
    Type aType = Type.GetType(string.Format("WatiN.Core.{0}.WatiN.Core", webElement.Tag));
    MethodInfo method = aType.GetMethod("TextField");
    method.Invoke(this.browser, webElement.Tag, findBy);
```

The key bits here are:

1. Get the Type
2. Get the Method
3. Invoke the method with the instance you want

There are shortcuts, and I probably don't have the specifics right for your question, but that should get you close to what you want.

Comment: Tyvm for reply. But your example has the same problem. "this.browser" is implemented hard coded. I want to implement it as a variable using it's string version. Only problem is, i have no idea how.

Comment: So you want to invoke "this.browser"? Or you want the instance that "this.browser" represents?

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go, threw this together in LINQPad, but should be more-or-less portable:

```
void Main()
{
    WatiN.Core.Browser theBrowser = new WatiN.Core.IE("google.com");
    Foo(theBrowser, "Id", "gbqfq", "TextField", "TypeText", "Search for this");
}

public void Foo(WatiN.Core.Browser browser, string findTypeBy, string search, string tagName, string elementMethodName, params object[] argsForMethod)
{
    var watinCoreAsm = Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("WatiN.Core");
    if(watinCoreAsm == null) return;

    var watinCoreTypes = watinCoreAsm.GetTypes();
    if(watinCoreTypes == null) return;

    var findType = watinCoreTypes.FirstOrDefault(type => type.Name == "Find");
    if(findType == null) return;

    var constraintInstance = findType.GetMethod("By" + findTypeBy, new Type[]{ typeof(string) }).Invoke(null, new[]{search});
    if(constraintInstance == null) return;

    var browserAccessor = browser.GetType().GetMethod(tagName, new Type[]{ constraintInstance.GetType() });
    if(browserAccessor == null) return;

    var resultElement = browserAccessor.Invoke(browser, new[]{ constraintInstance });
    if(resultElement == null) return;

    var elementMethod = resultElement.GetType().GetMethod(elementMethodName);
    if(elementMethod == null) return;

    elementMethod.Invoke(resultElement, argsForMethod);
}
```